# Virtual Fields and model aliases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I'm newbie in cakephp and a I have the next problem:

**Model: CostsCenter->Scholarship->ScholarshipsDetail**

**1. Virtual Field in Scholarship Model:**

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'code' => "UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTR(CostsCenter.name, 1, 3), '-',
     Scholarship.selection_year, '-', SUBSTR(Country.name, 1, 3), '-', 
     Postulant.number))");
```

**2. List all in the Controller from ScholarshipsDetail**

```
$scholarships_detail = $this->ScholarshipsDetail->find('all', 
          array('contain' => array('Scholarship' => array('CostsCenter')),
                'conditions' => array('ScholarshipsDetail.scholarship_id' => $scholarship_id)));
```

Then, I need list the ScholarshipsDetail, but I have the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CostsCenter.name' in 'field list'
```

I tried to apply "contain" in CostsCenter across Scholarship but the error still appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that doing a find using containable does not select ScholarshipDetail JOIN Scholarship JOIN CostCenter. 
If you look in the SQL debug output you will see that first it gets the ScholarshipDetail and Scholarship records, then it loops through these and adds the CostCenter records to the results array by doing individual selects on the CostCenter table. 
Therefore the CostCenter fields are not available to use in the virtual field and the query fails. [This link](http://www.endyourif.com/cakephp-containable-statement-pitfalls/) helps to explain this containable pitfall better.

If you really want to keep your virtual field, you should not use containable and set up the query **using [manual joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) instead**.

However, as you are going to frequently have this kind of problem because your virtual field references different models, it would be a better idea to **create a real field instead**. Try something like this:

- Create a field called code in the scholarships table
- Create a function eg `updateCode()` in the Scholarship model that formulates the code by selecting the correct information from the various tables and then updates the code field in the scholarships table.
- Call this function from the controller after any action that could affect the code, eg when a Scholarship record is edited (or consider putting it in the [afterSave callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave) of the Scholarship model)